# javascript setTimeout problem

Tags: javascript

Can any one tell me why i am loosing content in [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) checked in firebug and i am loosing the content, though i the height of the content is showing!
all replies are welcome!

```
function Tableslide_down(content,height)
   {
     var contentID = document.getElementById(content);
     if(contentID.offsetHeight < height)
    {
     contentID.style.top = parseInt(slidingDiv.style.top) + 10 + "px";
     setTimeout("Tableslide_down('"+content+"','"+height+"')",10);
     }
     contentID.style.display = "block";
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() { Tableslide_down(content, height); },10);
```

First parameter of setTimeout can (MUST) be a function.

Comment: +1 Every time you construct code from strings Jon Skeet kills a kitten.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the timeout to a variable:

```
var myto =  setTimeout("Tableslide_down('"+content+"','"+height+"')",10);
```

This also means you can clear it later if you need to:

```
clearTimeout(myto)
```